# Unable to install Hyperledger Composer on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install Hyperledger composer on Ubuntu 20.04 but I am getting error.
I am following the steps given on https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

But when I run `npm install -g composer-cli@0.20`, I get the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated composer-cli@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-wallet-inmemory@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-admin@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-documentation@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-wallet-filesystem@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-report@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-common@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-client@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-connector-proxy@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated composer-connector-hlfv1@0.20.9: Hyperledger Composer has been deprecated. Please see the README for more details: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.3.0: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fabric-ca-client@1.2.1: wanted: {"node":"^8.9.0","npm":"^5.5.1"} (current: {"node":"12.16.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fabric-ca-client@1.2.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fabric-client@1.2.1: wanted: {"node":"^8.9.0","npm":"^5.5.1"} (current: {"node":"12.16.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fabric-client@1.2.1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/samarth/.npm/_logs/2020-05-12T09_26_08_612Z-debug.log
```

How can I install Composer?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Hyperledger Composer is deprecated since Aug 2019. Your error message displays the warning as well

Please check the announcement at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/

Suggest you use chaincode and client applications written in Node / React etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to change tout npm version and node version
For example :
Npm v5.6.0
Node : 8.6.0